# check if noun before for,from,of is singular using regex

Tags: python, regex

So given this sentence:
`a benefit of investments`
to check if this is a singular expression, I am trying to grab a word before [for, from, of], so in this case it is `benefit`, and check if it is singular by checking if it ends with s (not ss - maybe have to use look back here?).
So the regex I got is
`\w*(?!s) for|\w*(?!s) from|\w*(?!s) of`

But it would also match `benefits of` (plural expression)

How can I modify my regexp?

Comment: Seems like a natural language processing library would do best here. Not all words that end in `s` are plural--or are you only interested in `benefits` solely?

Comment: In line with @ggorlen comment, have a look into the `nltk` package.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to match
If “s” must be present
\w+ (of|for) \w+s\b
If “s” must be absent
\w+ (of|for) \w+[a-rt-z]\b

These regexes are very basic and may need to be refined. \w matches not just alphabetic characters

Comment: Please note, this is more of a comment than an answer as it does not fully address the question.  High risk of downvotes.

Comment: The question is not clear, hence the possible solutions. Is not the purpose of this site to help question submitters to find the answer themselves?

Comment: I **fully** agree on the point of helping submitters to find answers themselves; in fact, I wish there was more of that! The purpose of answers is to provide a *solution*; whereas “here’s how to find it yourself” advice is better suited for comments.